# List files by using UNIX/Linux commands

Tags: linux, pipe

By using UNIX/Linux commands, pipes (“|”) and redirections (“>”, “>>”)
make a listing of the smallest 5 files in the “/etc” directory whose names
contains string “.conf”, sorted by increasing file size.

Comment: Is this an instruction?

Comment: How many credits do I get if I do your homework for you?

Comment: This is my first time posting a question here so I don't know what credits is and how I give it :P

Comment: It's your homework. SO can help with problems, but not solve your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
ls -lS /etc | sort -k 5 -n| grep ".conf" | head -n 5
```

First list files by size, then sort by 5th column of results by number, then filter lines containing the string *".conf"* and finally show only 5 lines.